# Blank plot when using cowplot with RNotebook

Tags: r, rnotebook, cowplot

Say I have the RNotebook below.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r}
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, hp))
plot_grid(g,g)
```
````

When I run this I get a blank plot and then the actual plot. This seems to be a new issue, as old code that used to run fine now does not. Do others have the same problem? Can anyone suggest why this happens and how I can prevent it?

#### sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] cowplot_0.9.1      ggplot2_2.2.1.9000

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] labeling_0.3      colorspace_1.3-2  scales_0.5.0.9000 lazyeval_0.2.1    plyr_1.8.4        tools_3.3.3      
 [7] gtable_0.2.0      tibble_1.3.4      yaml_2.1.14       Rcpp_0.12.14      grid_3.3.3        knitr_1.17       
[13] rlang_0.1.4       munsell_0.4.3
```

---

#### Edit

I downgraded to `ggplot2` 2.2.1 and still the problem persists. The blank panel appears both in the Rmd file before I render it as HTML and after in the HTML file. I've attached a picture of the HTML output. I tried running `grDevices::graphics.off()` before with no success. I forgot to mention before: I just upgraded to RStudio 1.1.383.

[image]

---

#### Aha!

This does **not** happen when I knit the file as a `html_document` rather than rendering it as a `html_notebook` using Preview, so presumably this is an RNotebook issue rather than an RMarkdown issue.

Comment: You're running the development version of ggplot2. Can you downgrade and test whether the problem remains? I haven't tested cowplot against the current development version yet, there may be issues.

Comment: Also, when you say "I get a blank plot and then the actual plot", do you mean in the rendered html? Finally, can you render twice in a row and see if the second time works?

Comment: Last comment: Can you run `grDevices::graphics.off()` before knitting and see whether that fixes the problem?

Comment: @ClausWilke Thanks for the replies, Claus. I've updated my question with the information you requested.

Comment: Your best bet may be to file a bug report with RStudio or RNotebook. The `plot_grid()` function needs to open a null graphics device to convert a ggplot2 object into a grob. There has been a long string of reports of empty plots popping up in the wrong places as a consequence of this. Nothing we have tried on the cowplot side has been reliably able to suppress the problem, because ultimately the problem resides with buggy R graphics devices. See e.g. lines 32 to 44 [here.](https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/blob/master/R/plot_to_gtable.R)

Comment: @ClausWilke Okay, will do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually, can you file an issue for cowplot as well?
 Maybe we can improve our workaround code. https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/issues

Comment: @ClausWilke Sure.

Comment: @ClausWilke Done.